# Dual Boot Backup Strategy - Straight Clone

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, backup

I hope I'm asking this in the right place. Let me know if I'm not and I'll move it.

For backup purposes, I've used Clonezilla to clone my laptop's dual boot HD (Windows7/Ubuntu 14.04) to an external HD. Clonezilla reported that the clone was successful.

I assumed I'd be able to plug the clone (external HD) into a different laptop, boot into it and be given the option of running Windows 7 or Ubuntu like I am on my main laptop. But all I'm getting is the Grub Rescue screen. I've been reading up all night on how to recover from this but so far I've tried the following and failed:

- Correct the prefix & root from Grub Rescue. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbJbi.jpg) for my attempt - I keep getting the message 'unknown filesystem' and am unable to do anything
- Use the boot-repair tool on a Ubuntu live USB. I did this and all it's done is install Grub on the second laptop without fixing the boot problem on the clone (external HD). See the report [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14512389/) from that process.  Now I have to get the Windows disk and repair it

I'd love to know how to fix this issue. I'd also love to know is this the best way of making backups of my laptop in case of failure.

Thanks for looking. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Right I've abandoned this strategy and am going to go with disk imaging.  I thought a straight clone would be simpler but having done more research, it looks like imaging is the backup strategy that most people use

Comment: Windows simply won't run from an  external hard drive.  As for linix based OSes, the source and target  disk would need to have the same geometry for this to atand a xhance of qorking

Comment: Cheers. I was going about it wrong alright